# bug in tikzqtree/tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree, tikzscale

## Background

I was trying to find out if I can use [`tikzscale`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) to scale the `tikz-qtree` figure in [Text tree using tikz-qtree is too wide, don't know how to break lines and make the tree compact](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94317/text-tree-using-tikz-qtree-is-too-wide-dont-know-how-to-break-lines-and-make-t/94323#94323) to fit in `\linewidth`. Unfortunately, instead of getting a scaled figure, I get a picture of code snippet in my `mygraph.tikz`.

## Codes

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mytree.tikz}

\end{document}
```

And here is `mytree.tikz`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.A
    [.B ]
    [.C
     [.D  ]
     [.E  ]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is [MMM's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7323/mmm) answer. He has already uploaded the patched [`tikzscale`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) package to ctan. I will open a bounty later, in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/pgfplots-how-can-i-scale-to-text-width/56473#56473) that led to this package, to express my appreciation to MMM's work on this package and his speedy reply. It was a little late in posting this but I hope that you can still benefit from the information here.*

## MMM's answer

Don't you get the correct tree as output at all? When using a slightly
adapted size (otherwise the height of the tree is too large to fit on a
page) like in

```
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{mytree.tikz}
```

I get the attached output file, which is the correct tree, I think. If you
do not get this output, please use the attached `sty`-file* and a recent
development variant of `TikZ/PGF`.

<sub>* Download the patched package in ctan instead</sub>

Although the tree is correct, the size of the nodes (with the meaning of
edges and nodes, i.e. graph speech) is very large, which is, what tikzscale
wants to avoid normally. `tikzscale` normally uses the `tikzpicture`'s scale
option to iteratively converge to the correct size as in `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]`.

This works, as `TikZ/PGF` defines, that scaling does not scale nodes (with the
meaning of coordinates and nodes, i.e. `TikZ` speech). Unfortunately, the
`tikz-qtree` package seems to ignore that definition. I am not sure, if that
was done on purpose (I've CC'ed its author), but I do not think that
`tikzscale` can do much as long as `tikz-qtree` does this scaling.

Did you have a look at the graph chapter in a recent development version of
`TikZ/PGF`? I think these graphs behave correctly regarding scaling, which
basically means, that they are unscalable at the moment.

You can try using code like the following

```
 \makeatletter
 \ifdef{\tikzscale@scale}{%
       % This is not commutative, as there is an error on commutation!
       \pgfmathsetlength{\parts}{\textwidth * \tikzscale@scale}%
 }{}%
 \makeatother
```

to get a dynamically sized variable `\parts`, which can be used to set the
node distance or something like that, to get a graphic which is scalable
with `tikzscale`, but this is all not officially supported, yet. Nevertheless,
I would be interested to hear about use cases.

## About the `tikz-qtree`

The author has expressed interest in fixing the scale implementation as suggested by MMM.