# Horizontal tikz-qtree level distance too big while using edge style

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

After tweeking with tikz-qtree a lot, i ended up with the result below. But i dont know why the level distance after `XML` node is too long, and even when setting the `level distance` for said level, the line still stays long and thick.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{paper}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% tree
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,babel,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,level distance=1.2in,sibling distance=.05in]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={thick, draw, edge from parent fork right},
         every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in,align=center},
         level 1/.style={sibling distance=-40mm},
         level 2/.style={level distance=10mm}}
 \Tree [.SGML {HTML 4.0} [.\node(x) {XML}; [ XHTML XML DOM [.XSL XSLT XSL-FO XPath ] XQuery DTD XSD SOAP WSDL RDF RSS SVG ] ] ]
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

edit: `.\node(x) {XML};` or `.XML` dont make a diffrence

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please edit your question and complete the code to make it a compilable document. Especially important when your document requires specialised packages and libraries.

Comment: What happens if you have `.XML` rather than `.\node(x) {XML};`?

Comment: A level distance of `10mm` is too small, I think. The edge gets drawn through it. But I'm not really familiar with `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: oh, sorry didnt pay attention to that, i filed the request and i'm trying to put up a compilable example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind changing packages, you could use the powerful `forest`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      grow'=east,
      text centered,
      draw,
      thick,
      minimum width=1in,
      text width=1in
    }
    [SGML [HTML 4.0] [XML [XHTML] [XML] [DOM] [XSL [XSLT] [XSL-FO] [XPath]] [XQuery] [DTD] [XSD] [SOAP] [WSDL] [RDF] [RSS] [SVG]]]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

Comment: i already found this package [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95881) but wasnt aware it supported horizontal and edge style, will gladly switch to it, thank you

Comment: @Tarik I just corrected my code to centre the text, as in your original. It's a very powerful package - well worth the trouble to switch!

Comment: some of its options would have made my earlier trees easier to build (sidway dashed branches), will switch all the tree to it as well, documentation can be found [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf)

Comment: @Tarik There are also a lot of good examples on this site if you search. That's how I came to start using the package.